# Adding reference to TextBox manually in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, grid

In Following WPF Code

```
//class level Variables
public TextBox _txtDef = new TextBox(); 
public TextBox _txtComment = new TextBox();

//Events
private void OnCommentsMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _txtComment = sender as TextBox;
}

private void OnDefinitionMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _txtDef = sender as TextBox;
}
```

Markup

```
<WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgDefinition" Header="Definition" 
                                           Visibility="Collapsed" Width="300">
  <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Definition, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtDefinition" 
               Text="{Binding Path=Definition, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               BorderThickness="0" ContextMenuOpening="DefinitionContextMenuOpen"
               MouseDoubleClick="OnDefinitionMouseDoubleClick">
      </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>

<WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgComment" Header="Comment" Width="200"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed">
  <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtComment" 
               Text="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               BorderThickness="0" MouseDoubleClick="OnCommentsMouseDoubleClick">
      </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</WPFtoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When I m clicking on a particular cell one of the two event mentioned above get fired and hence only the reference of that particular textbox get added whose event get fired.

Is there any way to add the reference of both textbox while any of the two event get fired.

Thanks

Comment: I Think i don't understand the question, but you already have access to both TextBox instances. From the look on you code, you have a code behind, which calls InitializeComponent so if you give an element a Name, you can acess this element via its name from code. Besides that, you could use Attached properties to store a reference of one text box to another, but you should be careful using hard references.

Comment: @dowhilefor the text boxes are in a template - so the name is not sufficient in and of itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not (IMO). You wrote a DataTemplate. This will instanciated for each entry in your grid. When the event is fired, you will get the TextBox as sender the event was fired for (as you already mentioned). But I don't see any chance to get the instance of the other TextBox (it may not be instanciated already)

Comment: Is there any workaround,  Actually on any of the doubleclick Event i have to send the value of TextBox to another window and after value get processed by that another window , i have to put that processed value back in these Textboxes.I am able to do this for any of one TextBox at a time (the one on which user double clicked)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: As I mentioned above, I don't see any workaround

Comment: Ya @Fischermaen . I m agree. I am talking about Is there any other way to achieve the same workflow that i mentioned on my comment rather than using the approach that I posted as Question.

Comment: You can use an event on the data grid to send the current edited row to a processing window and after processing data putting the results in the columns of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Firstly an answer, I think that this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx

may well give you what you need. But...

Why do you need to get both text boxes? I'd like to understand the code structure a bit more because what I see of it feels wrong.

Comment: On the double click of any text box i want to access the Text property of both textboxes to send the content of both to another page and later get the content back from page and assigned them to their respective textboxes.

Comment: You have two way data binding - so you should have the data in the text boxes?